# Installing PRAW

Tags: python, praw

I would like to install PRAW so I can make reddit bots and stuff, but all the install guides are confusing to me so could someone explain how to as noob friendly as possible.  I've had some experience with vanilla python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`praw` is best installed, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw), via `pip`. To install `pip`, you need `setuptools`. [Here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) is a simple guide on installing `pip` via setuptools.

Basically, download `ez_setup.py` and `get-pip.py`, two Python scripts that automatically get and install `setuptools` and `pip`. You'll want to run the following commands in the terminal in the same directory as the location of the files, in order:

```
python ez_setup.py
python get-pip.py
```

Finally, you'll want to use `pip` to get `praw`. `pip` is an executable file that is usually located in your python build directory. For example, in Windows, it's located in `C:\Python27\scripts`. You can add that directory to your system path variable, but right now you can just navigate to that directory where `pip.exe` is installed. Then, run the following command in the terminal:

```
pip install praw
```

Comment: setuptools and pip installed successfully but when I type "pip install praw" t comes up with some stuff and then "SyntaxError: invalid token"

Comment: Picture of the console https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/78nafe866jtwf2y/Screenshot%202014-01-19%2020.13.17.png

Comment: Do you by any chance have both Python3.3 and Python2.7 installed?

Comment: I went and asked on /r/redditdev and got it sorted it but thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I recently had trouble with this so I thought I would add what I did.

1. Install Pip - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
2. install praw `pip install praw`; This is done on your pc/mac/linux(?)
   [Installation guide](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html)
3. Register on reddit as a developer and register the app.  To be able to use the api you need to have a client_id and a client_secret.  Get those by registering [here](https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps/).  More information about the types of applications can be found [here](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/authentication.html#script-application).
4. Now you are ready to begin coding.  This is a good script to verify that you are connecting to the reddit api. The client_id and client_secret are from the previous step and the user_agent is a string that is unique to your app.  I used something like 'my first app by /u/myUsername'.  The password and username is your reddit login

Run this code and it should output your username.

```
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT_ID',
                     client_secret="CLIENT_SECRET", password='PASSWORD',
                     user_agent='USERAGENT', username='USERNAME')
print(reddit.user.me())
```