# Getting an exception while trying to install pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, praw

I want to install praw with `pip install praw` command but before I want to install pip, couldn't manage to do it.

> Collecting pip   Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting wheel   Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: pip, wheel Exception: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 784, in install
>       **kwargs   File "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)   File
>   "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,   File "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py",
>   line 345, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py",
>   line 316, in clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)   File "/var/folders/vv/v2drs0vd7jz6wlywr02cr3480000gn/T/tmpDdYH0a/pip.zip/pip/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 83, in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py",
>   line 157, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

Comment: Look at the last line in the error message, it says very clearly what the problem is.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214817/installing-praw it worked for me .

Comment: @Egek92 if you find your answer then you need to accept it. Other it will be down-voted or more late answers.

Comment: @sam I was waiting for the time limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't have permission to the Python folder.

Try

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip
```

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` worked. cheers

Answer (score 0):

It says it can't write to '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'. Adapt read-write rights on that folder or try `sudo pip install praw`

Answer (score 0):

Try using virtualenv or --user option for pip command

```
`pip install praw --user`
```